# Google Data Studio auth throw error on prompt=consent

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, looker-studio

When I send this request for authorization:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=uri&client_id=clientId&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio&access_type=offline&prompt=consent

I receive the error :
Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio]
If you are a developer of metricinsights.com, see the error details (error details contain only the request I sent).
Error 400: invalid_scope

but when I remove "prompt=consent" part I successfully get an auth_code and exchange on token but I don't receive a refresh token.
What is wrong?

I expect to receive refresh token on every auth

[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raNrr.png)